# Simple bash script working on launch of EC2 instance in default VPC but not when launching into custom VPC

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I launch an EC2 instance (t2, Linux) with the user metadata script below into the default VPC everything works and I can HTTP to my instance and see my html page. If I launch an EC2 instance of the exact same type and settings into my own **custom VPC** it does not work. By does not work I mean that the /var/www/html directory is not even created. Being the newbie that I am I can't see what the difference is. It's like when I launch it into the default VPC the resource has some kind of permissions that I guess I haven't set up when launching instances into my custom VPC. I just don't see where that would be as NACLS, Security Groups, Internet Gateways, Route Tables, Subnets etc wouldn't have anything to do with this I'd have imagined.

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y install httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
mkdir /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
echo "<html><h1>This is a test</h1></html>" > index.html
chmod 755 index.html
```

I have also tried

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /test
cd /test
echo "<html><h1>This is a tester</h1></html>" > index.html
chmod 755 index.html
```

Comment: It's most probably an issue with your network config stopping the machine getting out to the Internet. As a result, the yum install command fails and /var/www/html never gets created as part of the install process.

Comment: That didn't work. In order to test it I changed the script to exclude the first 3 lines installing and setting up httpd. I launched a new instance into my custom VPC and when I SSH into the box, again the www directory does not exist in var.

Comment: It won't as you have not installed httpd. The directory /var/www/html will only exists once httpd has been successfully installed. Sort your network configuration and it will sort this issue.

Comment: I have added my other additional script attempts, neither would fail due to a yum update not having external access. Simple directory creation isn't even occurring.

Comment: Just to give some feedback in case it's of any use to someone. The initial issue was indeed a network one as mentioned. I hadn't set up my NACL Inbound Rules to allow for return traffic from hosts on the internet responding to requests originating in the subnet. So basically adding an Inbound TCP rule for the ephemeral ports for my Linux instance. I verified this by checking /var/log/cloud-init-output.log which showed that yum was locked by cloud-init as it tried some update (failing because of the NACL ephemeral port rule omission) and therefore was not available when my script needed it.

Comment: ...also, the reason my simple script, that created a directory was not working is because, from AWS "By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only during the first boot cycle when an EC2 instance is launched." and I was stopping my EC2 instance, editing the userdata and then restarting. My edited script wasn't running.